# How do I merge array values fo a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-merge

I want to merge the values of a multidimensional array that was returned by a function. It contains duplicated values and I want to get rid of the duplicates. I only know that of arrays saved in different variables.
This is the array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                [0] => 0
                [2] => 2
            )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [1] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [content] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [2] => 2
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307674/how-to-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-multi-dimensional-array-in-php see if that's what you're looking to achieve.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks a lot. :0

Comment: You're welcome, *cheers*